# Launch modal when div rectangle clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to leverage the following modal example https://codepen.io/centem/pen/wrYeMV but instead of using a button to launch the modal I am trying to launch the modal when a div rectangle is clicked and capture its id before launching the modal. This is the pen with the rectangles. https://codepen.io/centem/pen/GQVGmw

This is the modal javascript from the example I am trying to borrow from:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting us to do it for you? :) What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to each of the rectangles and add a click event listener to each.

```
var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

    squares[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(this.id);
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }, false);
}
```

Complete example here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEKyKQ

Comment: Thanks Karl! I tried this method and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need javascript for it. Assuming you're using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="span4 proj-div" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#GSCCModal">Clickable content, graphics, whatever</div>

<div id="GSCCModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
      hidden="true">&times;  </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set class to all div

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

use `document.getElementsByClassName("foo");` instead of `document.getElementById("myBtn")`

Because, you can not set same ID for multiple elements. but you can set same class to multiple elements.

Comment: Hi Vipul, I edited this https://codepen.io/centem/pen/GQVGmw with the getElementsByClassName but it still does not launch the modal. Can you please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified js code: 
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

```
        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("content");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
    //alert($(this).attr('class'))
    $(".modal-content").find('p').append("This is the class: "+$(this).attr('class'))
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```